# fft - optimising code to eliminate image above Nyquist

Tags: algorithm, fft

My understanding is: if I do an FFT on (for example) 2048 data points, I will get data in the first 1024 points, representing frequencies up to 1/2 the sample frequency.
I have seen Decimation in Time (DIT) and Frequency (DIF) as ways to compute the FFT faster.

My question: is there a procedure that simply... does not bother with the upper half of the FFT? If I'm going to truncate / throw it away, surely I can save time by not calculating it to start with?

Comment: Conjugate symmetry is only true for real input.  Most of the computation for the upper half of an FFT result is also required for the lower half.  So a real input FFT only saves a bit from the first and last layer (out of O(log(N)) layers) of the FFT computation.

Answer (score 0):

You could save a little time -- the upper half of the transformed output costs a couple floating-point operations per entry. The asymptotic savings, though, are Theta(n), as compared to the total Theta(n log n) running time of the DIT and DIF strategies. See below for a circuit diagram of the DIT strategy: computing X[0..3] requires all of the E and O entries. The situation with DIF is similar.

[image]

"[DIT-FFT-butterfly](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DIT-FFT-butterfly.png#mediaviewer/File:DIT-FFT-butterfly.png)" by Virens - Own work. Licensed under CC BY 3.0 via [Wikimedia Commons](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/).